# Work around for yahoo mail slowness (using 100% cpu)

Tags: internet-explorer-8, flash-player, yahoo-mail

My yahoo mail is very slow sometimes.  When it is, I notice that IE8 is using 100% cpu.  Using sysinternals process explorer I discovered the thread using all the cpu in IE8 has Flash in the stackwalk.

I upgraded flash from 9 to 10, but the problem persists.  I'm about to edit hosts to block the flash content by redirecting the yahoo and ad click dns entries.  Is there some easier way to get flash to behave?

The fix for the long run will be switching to gmail.

Comment: Have you considered switching to Firefox?  There are a variety of Flash-blocking extensions.

Comment: Getting the wife to switch browsers may be the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can go under Options... to Mail Classic..., which will use the old Yahoo Mail program which is faster but not as pretty.

Comment: It's currently running mail classic